# Flutter firebase web google sign In error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin, flutter-web

Error: Unhandled error PlatformException(idpiframe_initialization_failed, Not a valid origin for the client:
http://localhost:62652 has not been registered for client ID
1025728717365-s20p9ubjkfogdb90sc6786iptmgdfhkb.apps.googleusercontent.com.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go
to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID.,
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#error_codes, null) occurred in Instance of
'SignInFormBloc'.

```
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:5032:11)
at http://localhost:62652/packages/bloc/src/bloc_observer.dart.lib.js:182:21
at sign_in_form_bloc.SignInFormBloc.new.onError
(http://localhost:62652/packages/bloc/src/bloc_observer.dart.lib.js:183:28)
at _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:37034:11)
at sendError (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30966:26)
at _BroadcastSubscription.new.[_sendError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30983:11)
at _BroadcastSubscription.new.[_addError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30909:27)
at http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:31609:34
at _SyncBroadcastStreamController.new.[_forEachListener] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:31459:13)
at _SyncBroadcastStreamController.new.[_sendError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:31608:31)
at _SyncBroadcastStreamController.new.[_addError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:31437:25)
at _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:37034:11)
at sendError (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30966:26)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription.new.[_sendError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30983:11)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription.new.[_addError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30909:27)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription.new.[_addError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34968:25)
at _MapStream.new.[_handleError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34926:24)
at _ForwardingStreamSubscription.new.[_handleError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34993:38)
at _RootZone.runBinaryGuarded (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:37034:11)
at sendError (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30966:26)
at _ControllerSubscription.new.[_sendError] (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:30983:11)
at async._DelayedError.new.perform (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34251:27)
at _StreamImplEvents.new.handleNext (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34328:15)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:34089:16)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:37333:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:37339:13)
at http://localhost:62652/dart_sdk.js:33110:9
```

Comment: have you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: @ChetanGoyal. yes You have to add SHA-1 Key in debug and release mode in firebase.

Comment: Ok Great. Thanks for the reply.